# Why my RegExp schema don't match on the validate function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a RegExp schema to accepted text, numbers but no specials characters:

```
//Regex.jsx

const searchRegex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ-',.\s]+$");
export default searchRegex
```

I call this schema in the component and check if the address matches the schema, to search only if the text matches the schema.

```
//SearchBar.jsx

import searchRegex from './Regex'
import searchLocation from './SearchLocation'

const SearchBar = () => {
const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
const [searchErr, setSearchErr] = useState(false)

   const validate = () => {
    if (searchRegex.test(address)) {
     setSearchErr(true);
    } setSearchErr(false);
   };

   return (
     <input
      name="text"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Address..."
      autoComplete="none"
      value={address}
      onChange={(event) => {
         setAddress(event.target.value)
         }}
         onKeyPress={(event) => {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
               validate()
            } if (searchErr) {
                 searchLocation()
            }
        }}
     />
   )
}

export default SearchBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have an `else` or a `return` in:

```
if (searchRegex.test(address)) {
 setSearchErr(true);
} setSearchErr(false);
```

the `setSearchErr(false);` is always called.

Comment: same result, always false

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fast-iitot?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your `validate` function is never called so you always keep the initial value (add a `console.log` at the beginning of the `validate` function to check). If you call it, it returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

No issue in your regex.

Just add `return` in `if` condition. So it does not execute the below code if the condition meets true.

```
const validate = () => {
  if (searchRegex.test(address)) {
     return setSearchErr(true);
   } 
   setSearchErr(false);
 };
```

Comment: same result, always false

Comment: Hey @gcbox999 What is wrong here? Is it not setting the `searchErr` to true or not calling `searchLocation`?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fast-iitot?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few typos in your example but other already answered that
But the issue is your regex : `^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ-',.\s]+$`

The period (<kbd>.</kbd>) in Regex is interpreted as "Any character" so you also have to escape it with a backslash (<kbd>\</kbd>)

Here's is your fixed Regex : `^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ-',\.\s]+$`

I suggest you to check out [Regex 101](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Thank you for this link, but searchErr return always false :( with ^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ-',\.\s]+$ RegExp and test carracter "A" or "1"...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fast-iitot?file=/src/App.js